# pytest fails when using io.BytesIO stream instead of PDF file

Tags: python-3.x, stream, pdfminer

I'm running pytest to check a function that uses pdfminer to convert PDF to text. The function works when doing $ python function.py and the result is what I expect it to be. I should also point out that I'm using a stream when parsing the file (io.BytesIO) and this stream is the reason my test fails.
Running pytest the function fails with a PDFSyntaxError.

```
# function.py

...
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.document import PDFDocument


req = requests.get(url_pointing_to_pdf_file)
pdf = io.BytesIO(req.content)

parser = PDFParser(pdf)
document = PDFDocument(parser, password=None) # this fails
...
```

pytest calls the **init** method in pdfdocument.py (part of the pdfminer library) and stops here:

```
for xref in xrefs:
    trailer = xref.get_trailer()
    ...
    if 'Root' in trailer:
        self.catalog = dict_value(trailer['Root'])
        break
else:
    raise PDFSyntaxError('No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?')
...
```

And this is what pytest shows when testing the function fails:

```
tests/test_function.py:11:
----------------------------------------------------
.../function.py:157: in function
**document = PDFDocument(parser, password=None)**

...

E    pdfminer.pdfparser.PDFSyntaxError: No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?
lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py:583:PDFSyntaxError
```

Running the test with a PDF file stored in the same directory as function.py is successful, so the culprit is the io.BytesIO format of the downloaded PDF file. Since I want to use a stream with function.py I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.